# an example on Lie bialgebra

Tags: lie-algebras

> **An example:** $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb C)$
>
> Let us consider the Lia algebra $\mathfrak g=\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb C)$, with basis
>   $$H=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix},
> \ X=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix},
> \ Y=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$$
>   and commutation relations,
>   $$[H,X]=2X,\ [H,Y]=-2Y,\ [X,Y]=H.$$
>   The dual vector space $\mathfrak g^*$ has the dual basis $H^*, X^*, Y^*$, where, by definition, $\langle H^*,H\rangle=1$, $\langle X^*,X\rangle=1$, $\langle Y^*,Y\rangle=1$, and all other duality brackets are $0$. We shall consider the following commutation relations on $\mathfrak g^*$,
>   $$[H^*,X^*]_{\mathfrak g^*}=\frac14X^*,
> \ [H^*,Y^*]_{\mathfrak g^*}=\frac14Y^*,
> \ [X^*,Y^*]_{\mathfrak g^*}=0.$$

**My question is:** how to get the final equation?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be $1.1$ [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=0oF6h4eT-50C&pg=PA117&lpg=PA117&dq=explicit+Lie+bialgebra+structure+on+sl_2(C)&source=bl&ots=sVOxpt6Kkr&sig=t8XeJUklatkgXMbM8Vxh2wQH2DE&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjZrMvRmMPeAhXM-aQKHel5D0cQ6AEwBnoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=explicit%20Lie%20bialgebra%20structure%20on%20sl_2(C)&f=false), in the book by Basil Grammaticos and K.M. Tamizhmani. The commutation relations are chosen such that $\mathfrak{g}\bowtie \mathfrak{g}^{*}$ is a Lie algebra having both $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{g}^*$ as subalgebras. The Lie bracket $[,]_{\mathfrak{g}^*}$ is recovered on page $117$ in an explicit way. In general, Lie bialgebra structures on $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb{C})$ are parametrised by the $3$-dimensional vector space $\Lambda^2(\mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb{C}))$.